# Div class background color change

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to change the background color of div whose class = thisphotobox.
All should happen after pressing the image inside of this div.
What do i do wrong? And what should i add to these onclick brackets?
This is the image:

```
  echo '<div class="thisphotobox">
    <img src="'.$numphotos['link'].'" alt="photo" class="photolink" onclick="clicked()">
    </div>';
```

And here goes the function:

```
   function clicked(thisphotobox){
     var div = document.getElementsByClassName("thisphotobox");
     elements.style.backgroundColor="red";
   }
```

I'm also thinking how to make it get "checked" as in checkbox.

Comment: this seems wrong, you are grabbing all the elements with class thisphotobox, but then you are using a element var that has not been create.  you should be doing a for loop on div(its an array) and setting style

Comment: I recommend removing your question about "checked as in checkbox" until you can figure out the basics of DOM manipulation.

Comment: Now i know what i have to read about on google. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Instead of `onclick="clicked()"`, write `onclick=clicked();`.

2) If there is only one div, you should try to give it an `id`, not a `class`. You can still use CSS to modify it if you want to. And, of course, `getElementsByClassName` becomes `getElementById`.

3) In `clicked()` you create a variable named `div`, but try to change the background color of an undeclared variable `elements`. Change it to `div`, or change `div` to `elements`.

+1 What do you mean with the "checked like a checkbox" part? If you want to store that you clicked on the image (and changed the background color), then you can declare a new variable (outside of the `clicked()` function, so you can access it from elsewhere), false by default, then you can change it from the function like this:
`variableName = true;`. This is the easiest method to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

look at your variable name.  You've set the result of the search to `div` but you're trying to set the background on `elements`.

Also, this question has nothing to do with PHP or MySQL.

Comment: It all starts from echo so i guess its php :D
But my bad about mysql sorry